# what is the restful service http code for update failure

Tags: http, rest

I am building a restful service, I know the http code from http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

However I don't find the http code in corresponding to update something failed with HTTP PUT operation?

Comment: What kind of failure do you mean?

Comment: Depends on _why_ it fails. Different causes, different responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the actual [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2) that enumerates HTTP response codes.

They have two specific recommendations:

- If the entity being PUT included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an earlier (third-party) request, return **409 Conflict**, with a list of the differences between the two versions in the response body
- Return **400 Bad Request** for an otherwise unsuccessful PUT, with an explanation of why it failed (in plain old English) in the response body

Comment: The HTTP status code registry is maintained by IANA, see http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml